# More than three tabs causes Google map to reload

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs

I'm using Jack Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator and finding that when I have four tabs my Google map will reload after I visit the last tab and then the map tab.
For example, with just HOME | MAP | SEARCH, I can tab to HOME and then MAP, or SEARCH and then MAP, and in either case the map displays without any loading. But with HOME | MAP | SEARCH | ABOUT, if I tab to ABOUT and then MAP, the entire map redraws. This is a huge memory leak.
Here's my implementation of the PagerAdapter:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  private String[] titles = {"Home", "Map", "Search", "About"};

  public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int index) {

      switch (index) {
          case 0:
              return new HomeFragment();
          case 1:
              return new MapFragment();
          case 2:
              return new SearchListFragment();
          case 3:
              return new AboutFragment();
      }

      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return titles.length;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return titles[position].toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

I've changed the order of the tabs but when there are four the last one will cause reloading if I go there before the map.

The tab source, TabPagerIndicator.java has an interesting method that might be a candidate for redrawing the map.

```
    @Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    final boolean lockedExpanded = widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
    setFillViewport(lockedExpanded);

    final int childCount = mTabLayout.getChildCount();
    if (childCount > 1 && (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY || widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)) {
        if (childCount > 2) {
            mMaxTabWidth = (int)(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) * 0.4f);
        } else {
            mMaxTabWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) / 2;
        }
    } else {
        mMaxTabWidth = -1;
    }

    final int oldWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final int newWidth = getMeasuredWidth();

    if (lockedExpanded && oldWidth != newWidth) {
        // Recenter the tab display if we're at a new (scrollable) size.
        setCurrentItem(mSelectedTabIndex);
    }
}
```

I'm unable to debug this however because Android Studio has issues locating the library.

```
Warning:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':libs/tabLibrary' (needed by module 'app'.)
Linking to library 'libs/tabLibrary-unspecified' instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't a memory leak exactly. By default `ViewPager` keeps the current page, the previous page and the next page in memory. It destroys all other pages to optimize the memory. Imagine if you have hundreds of pages in `ViewPgaer` and if all the pages are kept in memory, app will crash due to `OutOfMemory` exception :)

However in your case since there are only 4 tabs, you can keep all 4 tabs in memory. You can do so by setting `offScreenPageLimit`

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Please note that by doing this, all four pages of `ViewPager` will be loaded at once and will not be destroyed until the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a try and let you know.